# there is no property of datagridview in property windows

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm using Visual Studio 2008. I have no idea what happened, but all of a sudden I noticed that the Properties window for ALL of the DataGridViews in my project went blank. I've tried dropping in new ones..still blank. I restarted Visual Studio and my computer...still blank. I've done some google searches, and I've found people who have had the same problem, but there is no solution and it appears that Microsoft has been unable to duplicate it. Any ideas?

Comment: Try clearing the Reflected Schemas directory.... In my case its found in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas where username is your windows login or just search for ReflectedSchemas. I have found that periodically clearing this helps. Don't delete the directory just the files in it.

Comment: i serach this file name but i have no résult, may be because i have french version?

Comment: Its not a filename but a folder (directory)... I'm using Visual Studio 2010 but I'm sure that VS2008 has it too. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as Badr El Ouassif defined in my XP virtual machine, working with VS2008. In my case it was because I changed a folder's access security to read-only, since this folder needed a big ammount of hard disk capacity and I wanted VS not to write there.

c:\Documents and Settings[USER]\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ProjectAssemblies

The properties appeared as soon as I came back to establish the original configuration of the folder, full control for every user.